# User selecting item in map

Tags: c++, maps

I am currently writing a command line game program where I have stored the categories and solutions in a `map<string, vector<string>>`.  The key value is the category and the vector is a vector of solution strings.

I would like to prompt the user to select a category however I am unsure of the best way to do it as I don't want to force the user to manually type the category and therefore am only receiving an int with their selection.

Is there a way to use an int to access a map? (for example solutionMap[2] = the second value?)

Here is a snippet from my code just to clarify

```
cout << "\nCategories:\n-----------" << endl;
int categoryCount = 1;
for (map<string, vector<string> >::iterator it = solutionMap.begin(); it != solutionMap.end(); ++it){
    cout << categoryCount << ": " << it->first << endl;
    ++categoryCount;
}

// Prompt user for selection and save as currentCategory
int currentCategory;
bool isValid = false;

do{
    cout << "Please enter the number of the category you would like to use: ";
    cin >> currentCategory;

    // if cin worked and number is in range, continue out of the loop
    if (cin.good() && currentCategory <= solutionMap.size()){
        isValid = true;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid entry!" << endl;

        // Clear the buffer
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (!isValid);
```

What I would like to do at this point is send the number to the game class and have is select a random solution from the vector using the selected key value, however as far as I know I need the selection as a string to find it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I should add that I tried using an iterator and incrementing it by the value given-1 but couldnt seem to get that to work either. Although I was probably trying it incorrectly

Comment: why exactly do you need a map?  it seems like a creating a vector of structs that have the category name and solutions might be better.

Comment: The Categories and solutions are coming from an ifstream from a CSV file. The program has to be able to store this data even if the csv file changes. I decided a map would be the best way to store this info.  Still learning for the most part so taking that information and making structs is slightly above my abilities/know-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access your map using an integer index, you can proceed as follows:

```
 auto ix=solutionMap.begin();   // bidirectional iterator to the map 
 advance (ix,currentCategory);  // move the iterator
 cout << "choice is "<<ix->second<<endl;      // here you are
```

But be careful:  as soon as you insert/remove an element, the ordre of the elements might not correspond anymore to the menu you've displayed.

**How does it work ?**

Iterator to maps are bidirectional:  you can only advance or go-back by 1 element at a time.  **[`advance()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/)** repeats this operation the correct number of times

**Alternatives**

If you don't really use the map as associative array, and mostly use menus and indexes, you should opt for another variant, using a vector instead of a map:

```
 vector<pair<string, vector<string>> solutionMap;
```

You could then easily access the elements, using their index.  If you need to occasionnally find a specific element by using the key string, you could still use find_if().

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually tried doing exactly this but was unaware of the advance() function. I tried Adding to it like I could with a pointer to no success but I have it working now. Thanks again

Comment: @KeeganTales you're welcome !  The adding on an iterator is only possible for [random access iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). Iterators take into consideration the constraints of the underlying data structure. This is why map iterators are bidirectional  whereas vector iterators for example are random access.